# $.getJSON() function wont grab external api

Tags: javascript, jquery

This block of code works fine and alerts data.person1.name from a local .json file.

```
    $.getJSON("test.json", function(data) {
  alert("success");
  alert(data.person1.name);

 });
```

test.json

```
    { "person1" : {
    "name": "Morgan",
    "age": "30",
    "location": "Boston",
    "desire": "Singing",
    "fear": "Violence"
  },
  "person2": {
    "name": "Joss",
    "age": "42",
    "location": "Boston",
    "desire": "Hiking",
    "fear": "Irrationality"
  }
}
```

But if I try a external url , like this weather api nothing happens.(Note: I've removed the API key, it is correct and not the issue.)

```
    $.getJSON("api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=APIKEY", function(data) {
  alert("success");
  alert(data.main.temp);

 });
```

From the weather API

```
    {  
   "coord":{  
      "lon":-0.13,
      "lat":51.51
   },
   "weather":[  
      {  
         "id":800,
         "main":"Clear",
         "description":"clear sky",
         "icon":"01n"
      }
   ],
   "base":"stations",
   "main":{  
      "temp":284.106,
      "pressure":1035.85,
      "humidity":67,
      "temp_min":284.106,
      "temp_max":284.106,
      "sea_level":1043.66,
      "grnd_level":1035.85
   },
   "wind":{  
      "speed":4.57,
      "deg":97.0002
   },
   "clouds":{  
      "all":0
   },
   "dt":1475715629,
   "sys":{  
      "message":0.0188,
      "country":"GB",
      "sunrise":1475734202,
      "sunset":1475774762
   },
   "id":2643743,
   "name":"London",
   "cod":200
}
```

Could someone please explain why this is? I am a complete noob at jquery and somewhat familiar with js Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: First, have you checked the console for error messages?  Then, have you tried putting a full path to the external resource?

Comment: Console isn't giving any errors.
That is the full path (minus the http://) to my knowledge..

Comment: In the network tab, do you get a response from the api call?  You should use the full path for the api.

Comment: No its not showing in the network tab.. Im only getting jQuery library links

Answer (score 2):

Add http:// in front of the URL.

```
$.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=...", function(data){
    console.log(data);
 });
```

Comment: I actually needed to add this before it could work. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=.',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(data){
alert(data.main.temp);
  }
});
```

I searched around and found this alternative that grabbed a "jsonp".
It worked. Not sure why atm, ill do some digging and report back.